# how to get column data type and value in mysql

Tags: mysql-python

I need a query which gives column datatype and its value for data manipulation. For example, if I type a query like this `select * from table`; I need a response such as:

```
id  id type     fname   fname type  active  active type
1   integer     Tommy   varchar     True    boolean
```

Can anyone give me any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

describe [table name] will spit out the column names and types.  Another useful command is show tables - lists all the tables.

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM mydb.mytable;
```